# Django imports nested in a class not working after moving to the top

Tags: python, django

I have this piece of code in the project I'm working on:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model


class UsersConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'apps.users'
    verbose_name = 'Users'

    def ready(self):
        """Monkey-patches auth.User models to provide Student and Employee."""
        super(UsersConfig, self).ready()

        def get_student(self):
            if hasattr(self, 'student_ptr'):
                return self.student_ptr
            else:
                return None

        def get_employee(self):
            if hasattr(self, 'employee_ptr'):
                return self.employee_ptr
            else:
                return None

        UserModel = get_user_model()
        setattr(UserModel, 'student', property(get_student))
        setattr(UserModel, 'employee', property(get_employee))

        from django.contrib.auth import models as auth_models
        setattr(auth_models.AnonymousUser, 'student', None)
        setattr(auth_models.AnonymousUser, 'employee', None)

        import apps.users.signals  # noqa: F401
```

After moving import `from django.contrib.auth import models as auth_models` from inside the class to the top of the file, the project stops working.

Does it really matter in python/django where exactly in the code is the import located or is this a problem of other nature?

Comment: It's OK to import it there - it doesn't work at the top because it's literally not "ready" until that ready method is called. That said, I can't help thinking there must be a better way to achieve what you're trying to do, and that your models are perhaps ill-defined.

Comment: @michjnich Thanks, it's basically all I wanted to know for now as I'm working on tidying up the imports and I was wondering why does it actually matter here. I can't redo the models now but it's something I can mention to my team :)